# Custom page template not being called

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

I've been learning Wordpress for the last few days but I'm having an issue with custom post types.

I've registered the post type as below:

```
function create_kitchen_type() {
    $kitchen_args = array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Kitchens' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Kitchens' )
            ),
            'public'      => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'description' => 'Kitchen custom post type description',
            'supports'    => array(
                'title',
                'editor',
                'comments'
            ),
            'taxonomies'  => array('category'),
            'rewrite'     => array(
                'pages' => false
            )
    );
    register_post_type( 'kitchen_post', $kitchen_args );
};
add_action( 'init', 'create_kitchen_type' );
```

In index.php the post types (currently just one) are outputted like so:

```
$custom_post_args = array(
        '_builtin' => false,
        'public'   => true
);

$post_types = get_post_types( $custom_post_args, 'objects' ); 

foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
    echo '<a href="' . $post_type->name . '">' . $post_type->labels->singular_name . '</a>';
};

// Outputs: <a href="kitchen_post">Kitchens</a>
```

Then, when the link is clicked, the address bar displays `localhost/site_name/kitchen_post` but the title is "Page not found | ", and the single echo that I've added to archive-kitchen_post.php is not displayed.

So, why isn't archive-kitchen_post.php used?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out this was simply a case of going to Settings > Permalinks and merely saving. This reset the permalink structures.